# Регулярные выражения (все возможные цифры/символы/буквы)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как построить для роутера регулярное выражение страницы 404 (все возможные цифры/символы/буквы)?

Answer (score 2):

```
.*
```

и  поставить его последним в роутинге.

А вообще, обычно в настройках роутинга существует что-то типа `otherwise`.